# Tor Bridge Issue

Tags: bridge

Below is the first thing that pops up when I run Nyx.

[Warn]Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 1

Notices.log:

Feb 18 07:41:42.000 [notice] Registered server transport 'obfs4' at '[::]:6969'

Feb 18 07:41:44.000 [notice] Self-testing indicates your ORPort is reachable from the outside. Excellent. Publishing server descriptor.

Feb 18 07:41:48.000 [notice] Performing bandwidth self-test...done.

Feb 18 07:47:43.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

Feb 18 08:30:04.000 [notice] Received reload signal (hup). Reloading
config and resetting internal state.

Feb 18 08:30:04.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".

Feb 18 08:30:04.000 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.6 opening log file.

Feb 18 08:30:04.000 [warn] Pluggable Transport process terminated with status code 1

Feb 18 08:33:31.000 [notice] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

As who are you running the nyx command? I suggest as debian-tor user

```
sudo -u debian-tor nyx
```

or as root

```
runuser -u debian-tor nyx
```

And whats in your torrc regarding control port? Like port number, cookie authentication etc.